# How to put different images on foreach in php

Tags: php, html, image, foreach

i'm doing a training in PHP, i'm still learning, and i'm trying to make a "poor video-game advertise", i got my php file in a folder, and a folder named "img" inside the same folder. Well, all i want to know is hows do i make to show a different image for a different game ? I'm trying to at least show Watch_Dogs img, but it isn't showing as well... And i need to show the correct image for the correct game, can anyone help me out ? here's the code, it's pretty poor i know...:

```
<!Doctype HTML>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <title> Repetição em PHP </title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
    $arrayGames = array("Watch_Dogs " => " R$199,90",
                         "Dead Space " => " R$149,90",
                          "Wolfenstein " => " R$189,90");
        foreach($arrayGames as $titulo => $preco){
            echo"<p>Jogo: " . $titulo . "<img src='img/watch_dogs.jpg' /> </p>" . $preco;
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try adding a `/` before 'img/watch_dogs.jpg'

Comment: Hey bro, so, the thing is that they aren't in a before folder, they are in the img folder, and even with de / it don't work... i tried to make a html file with the code and the img appeared perfectly.

Comment: hit `CTRL + U` in your browser to view the HTML source code to see if anything is out of place. You should be able to click the link in 'src=' to see where it takes you.

Comment: which are the names of your images?

Comment: @nismoracerx did it but it seems to be everything ok, but i clicked the src link and it won't lead me anywhere...

Comment: @artur99 watch_dogs.jpg, dead_space.jpg, wolf_new_order.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <?php 
    $arrayGames = array("Watch_Dogs " => array(" R$199,90","watch_dogs.jpg"),
                         "Dead Space " => array("R$149,90","dead_space.jpg"),
                          "Wolfenstein " => array("R$189,90","wolfenstein.jpg")
                        );
        foreach($arrayGames as $titulo => $preco){
            echo"<p>Jogo: " . $titulo . "<img src='img/{$preco[1]}' /> </p>" . $preco[0];
        }
    ?>
```

The image you are showing must be relative to your php file location.

Ex:

```
CURRENT_FOLDER
 |_ file.php
 |_ <img>
     |_ watch_dog.jpg
     |_ ... .jpg
```

Comment: Hey man, thx, i just couldn't say if it's really working 'cause the imgs aren't showing yet, but i'm solving this and as soon as i can, i'll be posting it here !

Comment: Suddenly the imgs appeared haha, thx man ! thx to everyone who helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the data on your array as multi-dimenional:

```
$games = array("Watch_Dogs " => array("price"=>" R$199,90","img"=>"http://placehold.it/350x150"),
               "Dead Space " => array("price"=>" R$199,90","img"=>"http://placehold.it/350x150"),
               "Wolfenstien " => array("price"=>" R$199,90","img"=>"http://placehold.it/350x150")
               );

$html = '';
foreach($games as $game_title =>$price_img)
{
    $html .= "<p>Jogo: {$game_title} <img src='{$price_img['img']}' /> {$price_img['price']} </p>";
}

echo $html;
```

[DEMO](http://codepad.org/lRehFe1V)

Comment: Thx for the help man, still, i can't say if it really worked because the img aren't showing up yet... But i'm working and soon as i can solve that i'll be posting here !

Comment: did you use the link i provided, yours must be the path for your image, the link i provided was just for demo.

Comment: Though i'm using the correctly path, it's not working :/

Answer (score 0):

You need to derive the leading part of the file name from the array key. And you need to remove the trailing spaces on the key names before appending the .jpg.

In my suggested solution, I've elected to modify the key to remove the trailing space; if the trailing space is important, you'll need to rtrim the key before using it.

```
    <!Doctype HTML>
    <html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
    <title> Repetição em PHP </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
         $arrayGames = array("Watch_Dogs" => " R$199,90",
                             "Dead Space" => " R$149,90",
                             "Wolfenstein" => " R$189,90");
         foreach($arrayGames as $titulo => $preco ) {
             echo"<p>Jogo: " . $titulo . "<img src='img/" . $titulo . ".jpg'/> </p>" . $preco;
         }
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I guess you gave the best answer ! Though the imgs still not showing, i presed ctrl+u in the page and the images are correctly spcified in the correct games. How  does that work, could you explain please ?